# Как обратиться к последнему элементу?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,есть div и в нем еще три div, id родительского получаю и записываю его в переменную key2, не могу обратиться к дочернему элементу в этой ситуации:

```
var key2 = snap.key; //тут получаю id родительского элемента
$('#' + key2 :last-child) // как обратиться к последнему дочернему элементу
```

Comment: [Документация](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector)

Comment: стоит добавить html, к которому применяется скрипт с указанием какой именно элемент нужно получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код из вопроса вполне рабочий, если исправить ошибку сбора строки.

```js
var key2 = 'container'; //тут получаю id родительского элемента
$(`#${key2} :last-child`).html('я последний');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```